# how to set radio button in python and tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code (in python and tkinter):

```
c1 = tk.Radiobutton (frm, text='a',variable= radioValue ,value=1)
c2 = tk.Radiobutton (frm, text='b',variable= radioValue ,value=2)
c3 = tk.Radiobutton (frm, text='c',variable= radioValue ,value=3)
c4 = tk.Radiobutton (frm, text='d',variable= radioValue ,value=4)
```

then I retrieve a value called `r` from database, it is between 1 and 4.

I use `r` to set a radio button to on by using many if statements, and it works well. The if statements are:

```
if (r==1): 
    (c1.select())
if (r==2): 
    (c2.select())
if (r==3): 
    (c3.select())
if (r==4): 
    (c4.select())
```

Is there a better solution instead of multiple if?

Comment: You can save your radio button in a dict with `key` referring to the radio button of its value then later use `get` method of the dict.

Comment: Use `radioValue.set(r)`.

Comment: use `elif` after `if`. no need to check rest of them

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the tkinter variable `radioValue` to set the active radiobutton:

```
radioValue.set(r)
```